# Error a realizar consulta en la base de datos con laravel :: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Tags: php, laravel, json, utf-8

Estoy utilizando una base de datos postgresql y un proyecto hecho en laravel. El problema que tengo es al momento de realizar la consulta a la base de datos. En el log me da el siguiente error "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar el código PHP, SQL y cómo conviertes el JSON?

Comment: Tuve un problema similar a ese y lo solucioné cambiando el cotejamiento de la BD completa, tenía **utf8mb4** y lo cambié a **utf8_general_ci** y desapareció el error.